# Android ListView with SQL id

Tags: android, android-listview, android-database

I'm working on an app where user will be able to view a list with names, and when he clicks on one, another activity pops up with more details regarding the chosen profile. I've got a ListView. I create it using this code:

```
listContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContacts);
        data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> sex = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> age = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> sexnage = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {

            names.add(cn.getName() + " " + cn.getSurname());

            sex.add(cn.getSex());
            age.add(cn.getAge());
            id.add(cn.getID());
            sexnage.add(cn.getSex() + " " + cn.getAge());
        }

        titleArray = new String[names.size()];
        titleArray = names.toArray(titleArray);

        subItemArray = new String[sexnage.size()];
        subItemArray = sexnage.toArray(subItemArray);

        for(int i=0;i<titleArray.length;i++){
            HashMap<String,String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datum.put("Name", titleArray[i]);
            datum.put("Sex and Age", subItemArray[i]);
            data.add(datum);
        }


        SimpleAdapter subAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {"Name", "Sex and Age"}, new int[]
                {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        listContacts.setAdapter(subAdapter);
```

How can I set ID of each element in List, so that it corresponds to Database one?

Comment: create custom adapter. make list of pojo class with variable "Name", "Sex" etc  and pass it to adapter.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this without creating class?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) as listview adapter.